# Does ini_set('session.save_path', 'custom path'); effect the session garbage cleaner?

Tags: php, session

Does `ini_set('session.save_path',  'custom path');` effect the session garbage cleaner?

As I'm setting a custom directory for the sessions, because I've read from various php security guides, that setting a custom directory on shared hosting for sessions; can improve session security.

But the problem is I've read somewhere that PHP does/handles the session garbage cleaning only when the session_save_path is the default and not modified (ie. using a custom directory)? - is this true, if so is their a solution for this?.

(take into consideration I'm using shared hosting).

Appreciate all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The garbage collector kicks in before control is handed over to your script, so when the GC kicks in, the save_path set in php.ini will be in effect, not the path you're overriding with.

Essentially, you cannot use the default garbage collector if you override the save_path from within your scripts. The session files will be stored in the override directory, but the GC will look in the previous dir, which would now have no session files in it.

Comment: So is their a way to emulate the functionality of PHP's garbage collector - when the save_path is overrided with a custom path? (example code is appreciated).

Comment: You don't have to, just set the custom path in the php.ini, so the override is present when PHP starts up. That way the GC will know you're storing the sessions somewhere else and will look there. Other than that, you'll have to build your own. Basically scan the dir, look for files older than your timeout period, and nuke them

Answer (score 0):

There are some distributions that set `session.gc_probability` to `0` and clean up old sessions using a cron job. In such a configuration, a custom path effectively prevents clean up. If this is the case with your installation, set `session.gc_probability` and `session.gc_divisor` to values grater than `0`.